# Field focused tooltip vs. clickable information icon

Tags: forms, tooltips

I'm building a public website and I need to display helpful information to guide the user when filling in forms. The forms may contain text inputs, dropdown lists, sliders... The site will be mobile compatible.

I have thought of 2 ways to display the tooltip:

- The tooltip is displayed when the user focuses on the field
  **Pros:** does not clutter UI
  **Cons:** Users might miss it if they don't click in the field, and just leave the page.
  Information is always shown when field is focused, user might not need it.
- The tooltip is displayed when the user clicks a "?" icon
  **Pros:** Information shown only when needed.
  User will easily find help
  **Cons:** Clutters UI
  Usually, "?" icons are not clickable

What would be the best practice here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It depends on how often you expect help to be needed.**

- A clickable `?` icon is a good way to go if the answer will usually be clear without any explanation, but help might be needed occasionally.  It is easily accessible, but doesn't get in the way for the majority of users who don't need it.

  I have seen plenty of sites use this paradigm, and it generally is quite clear.  The key is to use styling to show that the `?` is clickable. Often it looks like a small, round button.
- If there is an explanation that will always be needed in order to complete the form, you should have that appear when the field is highlighted, or even always be visible on the page.

  One example of this I have seen is passwords that must meet certain strength requirements (must contain special characters, be at least 12 chars long, etc.).  Users can't be expected to know your custom rules, so it must be shown.  Either rules are displayed statically on the page, or Javascript is used to dynamically validate the password and indicate what is missing.

Pick what seems most appropriate for your situation.

Comment: If I have a form with some straight forward fields and other fields that require an explanation, would it be OK to mix both techniques ? if not, which one to use ? I suppose it would be best to have the same "tooltip style" in the whole application ? Thanks

Comment: @ThunderDev, I think mixing both techniques would be fine, as long as it is well-presented overall.

Comment: I think I will just go with always displaying the information, and maybe a hoverable tooltip "show more" link if the text is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to hide the information (on focus/on click). If there is no restriction on space, I would go with incontext labeling and examples.

- Treat your users as intelligent people.
- Do not talk as if you are ordering : "Email address" instead of "Enter your email address"
- Give examples of expected data
- Notify formatting or any other special cases

The advantage of this design is, even if the user is not familiar what the information needed is, the example provides additional details on what is expected. *Remember how Credit Card forms show where to find the security/CVV number.*

Making the information always visible is good since the user knows that it exists. If you are using on focus tooltips, user is not sure if all the fields will have tool-tips when he arrives. Can look daunting to see a page length form with only first field having any example/explanation.

Using `?` will save you space, but, it **forces the user to click on the icon** every time they need help. Can get **discouraging if it happens too often** ('I am stupid :-(' ) Better have the help always visible and easy access.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgB3ab.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Not sure about in-context labeling, I think the average person would feel more comfortable with a classic label. Good point about the "?" button.